# teradata: Converting column names to column values

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table with column names

```
ID, X1, X2, X3
```

and contains column values like

```
1, Hi, Hello,NULL
2, NULL,Hello123,XXX
```

the output should be

```
1 X1 
1 X2
2 X2
2 X3
```

The null values needs to be filtered out and the column names should come as column values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine two things:

1) TITLE -> this function will put the Title / ColumnName into the ColumnValue

2) UNPIVOT -> This Function will place the columns aside into rows among each other